# How to use graphics.h in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: graphics, gcc

I'm trying to use graphics.h in my ubuntu 20.04 with gcc and I don't know why it's not working. It's showing Unknown sequence number while processing queue error.

Here's my code:

```
#include <graphics.h>

int main()
{
   int gd = DETECT,gm,left=100,top=100,right=200,bottom=200,x= 300,y=150,radius=50;
   initgraph(&gd,&gm,NULL);
   rectangle(left, top, right, bottom);
   circle(x, y, radius);
   bar(left + 300, top, right + 300, bottom);
   line(left - 10, top + 150, left + 410, top + 150);
   ellipse(x, y + 200, 0, 360, 100, 50);
   outtextxy(left + 100, top + 325, "C Graphics Program");

   delay(5000);
   closegraph();
   return 0;
 }
```

Error:

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue  
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
txt: ../../src/xcb_io.c:260: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' 
failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I try to use XInitThreads but it still showing the same error.

For compiling I'm using following command:

```
gcc -o txt txt.c -lgraph -lX11
```